# Verify if li value contain one or more values

Tags: jquery

I have this script to filter my  values ​​but it only works when the value is single, if it is multiple it does not recognize it.

My code: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/e7thomazi/pen/oNjZBLL)

```
<li id="image_li_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="ui-sortable-handle card" data-filtertext="<?= $parse_to_tag($row['id']);?>">
```

Eg. select value = "4" OK / select value = "1 4 8" don't filter.

```
<li data-filtertext="4 8 10"> //not filter when select 4 or 8 or 10

<li data-filtertext="4"> // working fine.
```

But I need to filter when li value **contain** "1 or 4 or 8"

```
   $('#filter_categoria').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".reorder_ul").find("li").hide()
        $.each($("ul").find("li"),function(){
            if($(this).data('filtertext') == value)
                $(this).show();
        });

    });
```

Comment: can u give more html

Comment: What are the values in `$('#filter_categoria')`? I would also like to comment, and say there is almost no point in using jQuery these days.

Comment: [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the `"1 4 8"` string by spaces, then check each part individually

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal by splitting the list of numbers by `" "` and then verifying if the value (should be a string) you want is included in the list, like this:

```
if($(this).data('filtertext').toString().split(" ").includes(String(value)))
```

```js
  $('#filter_categoria').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".reorder_ul").find("li").hide()
    $.each($("ul").find("li"), function(){
      if($(this).data('filtertext').toString().split(" ").includes(String(value)))
        $(this).show();
    });
 });
 
 $('#filter_categoria').change();
```

```css
ul li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="filter_categoria">
  <option>4</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option selected>5</option>
</select>

<ul class="reorder_ul">
<li data-filtertext="4 8 10">4 8 10</li>
<li data-filtertext="4">4</li>
<li data-filtertext="5">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Haven't any progress, when use this not return, any li. I have edited my post with correct <li>

Comment: @EvertonThomazi you are correct, there was a `toString()` missing, I've updated my answer.

Comment: here your code snippet run correctly, but in my page didn't. I'm using PHP 7.0 have some difference?

Comment: There's no php involved in this. Try debugging your code using something like chromme developer tools

Comment: Console return "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"

Comment: Thats because `data-filtertext` was not found. Can you add your html code to the question?

Comment: Please make sure, on the browser, that there are any `li` inside the `<ul class="reorder_ul reorder-photos-list">`